# C# "a constant value expected" error out of nowhere

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I made some changes to a C# project using Visual Studio 2008. When I try to compile I get an instant error "CS0150 - a constant value is expected". However the compiler doesn't tell me where this error is supposed to happen neither a code line nor even the *.cs file. The output goes like this:

```
------ Build started: Project: MyProgram, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
error CS0150: A constant value is expected
```

Where is this error coming from and how to get rid of it? I'm sure I didn't changed any "switch" statement like the MSDN suggest. I also tried upgrading the project to Visual Studio 2010, but that didn't helped.

Comment: What did you change and can you share it? If it worked before, but doesn't work now, it's likely in those changes.

Comment: Do you have a `switch` statement in your code somewhere? Look at the case labels, the answer should be there.

Comment: Also examine if you're assigning non-constant values to attributes.

Comment: Attribute values also need to be constant values

Comment: I changed a lot of things (obviously) but none of them was related to a switch statement. 
I expected some errors but none without a hint where to look for. 

I indeed assigned a non-constant value to an attribute, that was a good hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pseudo-code caused this error:

```
private static int NumEntries = 2;
private string[] Strings = new String[NumEntries] {"123", "abc"};
```

For some reason the compiler didn't tell me where the error happened, so I hade to search my whole project.